# Play as zombies in split-screen Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare 1

Tags: ps4, plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

In the Playstation 4, split-screen version of Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare (the first one), is it possible to play as the Zombies instead of as Plants? I don't see any option to switch this.

I don't understand why we're earning all these zombie cards, from the sticker shop, if we can't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot play as a zombie in Split Screen mode. Zombies are only playable in PvP modes (Welcome Mat, Team Vanquish, Gardens & Graveyards, etc.).